# Generate exponential distribution of event times

Tags: matlab, statistics, exponential-distribution

I have to generate event times in the time interval [0; T] with T = 2000 s such that the
waiting times between consecutive events are exponentially distributed with mean
u = 0.4 s. Then counting the number of events per second.

I thought I could start by looking at each event time as the sum of all previous waiting times. But I am not allowed to use loops in my script. So that's a bit tricky

Finally fitting it all in a Poisson
distribution to the T counts and making a histogram out of it.

Edit: This is what I got so far:

```
C=colormap('lines');
fig=1;
fig=fig+1;
distr=makedist('Poisson')
my=0.4
distr.lambda=1/my;
disp(['Distribution mean,var,std,median,iqr=  ',num2str([distr.mean,distr.var,distr.std,distr.median,distr.iqr],'%8.4f  ')])
xupp=distr.icdf(0.999);
xupp=ceil(xupp/2)*2;
x=0:xupp;
figure(fig)
clf
% plot probability function
subplot(2,1,1)
bar(x,distr.pdf(x),0.1)
xlabel('$x$')
ylabel('$f(x)$')
title('Poisson distribution')
% generate random numbers
r=distr.random(500,1);
subplot(2,1,2)
box on
hold on
h=histogram(r,-0.5:xupp+0.5);
set(h,'Visible','off');
counts=h.Values;
hp(1)=bar(0:xupp,counts/sum(counts),0.1,'facecolor',C(1,:));
hp(2)=plot(x,distr.pdf(x),'p:','color',C(2,:));
distf=fitdist(r,'Poisson')
hp(3)=plot(x,distf.pdf(x),'p:','color',C(3,:))
xlabel('$x$')
ylabel('$f(x)$')
title('Data from Poisson distribution')
legend(hp,'Histogram','True distribution','Fitted with Poisson distr.')
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include your attempt, even if it is with loops. That way we can help you debug where necessary, as opposed to writing the complete code. Also, if you write a simple loop, that can often be vectorised using native MATLAB syntax, without changing the idea or result of the code.

Comment: You probably want a (homogeneous) [Possion point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process): points are independent and [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Defined_in_higher_dimensions), and their consecutive differences are [exponentially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process)

Comment: I tried using Poisson as you mentioned, but I am not quite sure this is the correct approach?